# Lua crashed when calling a script function from a C++ function called from script

Tags: c++, lua, lua-api

In brief, I called Lua script function `aaa`, `aaa` called C++ function `testfunc`, and when `testfunc` going to call script function `bbb`, it crashed.

This is the Lua-side code:

```
foo = 100
function aaa()
    testfunc(foo * 2)
end
function bbb(...)
    for val in ... do
        print(val)
    end
end
```

This is the C++ `testfunc`, it calls `bbb` with 3 arguments:

```
int testfunc( lua_State* lua )
{
    auto arg1 = lua_tointeger( lua, 1 );
    juce::Logger::writeToLog( "testfunc called with argument " + juce::String( arg1 ) );

    int bbb_type = lua_getglobal( lua, "bbb" );
    if ( bbb_type != LUA_TFUNCTION )
    {
        lua_pushstring( lua, "bbb is not function" );
        lua_error( lua );
    }

    lua_pushinteger( lua, 100 );
    lua_pushinteger( lua, 200 );
    lua_pushstring( lua, "deep dark fantasy" );
    lua_call( lua, 3, 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

In the stack trace of the crash, it seems that in `luaD_precall`, it does not think the incoming thing is an object, the `switch` branch went to the last `default`section that try to find the callable from __call `metamethod`. However, the type of function object in stack has been checked in `testfunc`.

Comment: The first argument for `bbb()` must be an iterator (see syntax for generic `for` in Lua manual).  In your case Lua is trying to call number `100` because you have passed it instead of iterator.

Comment: You're basically doing `for val in 100, 200, "deep dark fantasy" do`. Do you actually want to do `for _, val in ipairs{100, 200, "deep dark fantasy"} do`?